# Load data in Treeview in date order C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Is it possible to load data in to Treeview in date order from a text file? I have some .txt files that i load in to a Treeview. In those .txt files i have a `Name` and a `Start date` and i want to load those Names in date order.

Right now i have :

```
string[] animeMainNodeString = animeMainNode.ToArray(); // Parent Nodes Array

List<string> animeSubNodesList = new List<string>();

// Add a child for each Parent in array
for (int i = 0; i < animeMainNodeString.Length; i++)
{
    string name = animeMainNodeString[i]; // Parent name in array

    //Search for a .txt files in folders with Parent Nodes names
    foreach (var subnode in Directory.GetFiles(animeGroupPath + "\\" + name, "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).OrderBy(f => f))
    {
       //Read a text file
       var animeFileRead = File.ReadAllLines(animeGroupPath + "\\" + name + "\\" + subnode + ".txt");
        // Titel from this text file
       string Title = animeFileRead[0].Substring(animeFileRead[0].IndexOf('=') + 1);

        // Start Date from text file
       string startDate = animeFileRead[7].Substring(animeFileRead[7].IndexOf('=') + 1);
       string TitleStart = Title + "," + startDate;

        // Add to a list where are all names/start dates from this Parent       
       animeSubNodesList.Add(TitleStart);
     }

     /*
     * Here i want to somehow sort the Names by start date
     * but i have no idea if this is possible.
     */

     foreach (var item in animeSubNodesList) // Add childNode to parent
     {
        tvGroups.BeginUpdate();

        tvGroups.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(item);

        tvGroups.EndUpdate();
     }
}
```

The date and the name looks like this in text file : `Title=Test`   `StartDate=1986-12-20`

Sory for a mess of a code , i'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot easier with a typed list. Im not sure but afterward you may be able to bind the entire list to the treeview without iterating through it.

```
public class AnimeInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string TitleStart { get; set; }
}


        string[] animeMainNodeString = animeMainNode.ToArray(); // Parent Nodes Array

        List<AnimeInfo> animeSubNodesList = new List<AnimeInfo>();

        // Add a child for each Parent in array
        for (int i = 0; i < animeMainNodeString.Length; i++)
        {

            string name = animeMainNodeString[i]; // Parent name in array

            //Search for a .txt files in folders with Parent Nodes names
            foreach (var subnode in Directory.GetFiles(animeGroupPath + "\\" + name, "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).OrderBy(f => f))
            {
                AnimeInfo info = new AnimeInfo();
                //Read a text file
                var animeFileRead = File.ReadAllLines(animeGroupPath + "\\" + name + "\\" + subnode + ".txt");
                // Titel from this text file
                info.Title = animeFileRead[0].Substring(animeFileRead[0].IndexOf('=') + 1);

                // Start Date from text file
                info.StartDate = animeFileRead[7].Substring(animeFileRead[7].IndexOf('=') + 1);
                info.TitleStart = info.Title + "," + info.StartDate;

                // Add to a list where are all names/start dates from this Parent       
                animeSubNodesList.Add(info);
            }
            animeSubNodesList = animeSubNodesList.OrderBy(x => x.StarteDate).ToList();
            /*
            * Here i want to somehow sort the Names by start date
            * but i have no idea if this is possible.
            */

            foreach (var item in animeSubNodesList) // Add childNode to parent
            {
                tvGroups.BeginUpdate();

                tvGroups.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(item);

                tvGroups.EndUpdate();
            }
```

Comment: StarteDate is a string. Did you try to order by string?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and posting it here :) Everything works !

Comment: NP. How January first is represented in StartDate? "1984 - 01 - 01" or "1984 - 1 - 1"?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `StartDate` to `DateTime` and then order the list before adding to the tree:

```
var ordered = animeSubNodesList.OrderBy(x => ConvertToTime(x.StartDate));

foreach (var item in ordered) // Add childNode to parent
{
        tvGroups.BeginUpdate();    
        tvGroups.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(item);    
        tvGroups.EndUpdate();
}


private static DateTime ConvertToTime(string time)
{
            return DateTime.Parse(time.Replace(" - ", "/"));
}
```

Anyway, I would prefer to have the `StartDate` field type as `DateTime` in `AnimeInfo` and to run the conversion to `DateTime` (one time only) when reading from the file.

In addition, you didn't mention how one digit month and day are represented (1986/01/01 or 1986/1/1) so I suggested a solution with date conversion that works for any case. Using the later representation, order by string is not enough:

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>();
dates.Add("1986 - 1 - 1");
dates.Add("1986 - 2 - 1");
dates.Add("1986 - 10 - 1");
var ordered = dates.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); // wrong order

// ordered = {"1986 - 1 - 1", "1986 - 10 - 1", "1986 - 2 - 1"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time , i have done it as u wrote and as @Rick james wrote with `AnimeInfo` and converted to DateTime